# How to cut portions of the first field and the rest of the fields in one shot?

Tags: shell, unix

Following is the output of a process, that I am working.

10/19/2011 14:11:52.911728, 15277, 828, 2964, 1, 1

10/19/2011 14:11:53.915060, 34298, 898, 3096, 1, 1

However, using this output, I need to generate the average for each minute. Thus, I'm writing a shell program to just output all of these with the first field showing only hours and minutes and not the seconds and microseconds.

Wondering, what is the best way to generate only the hours and minutes from the first field and the rest of the fields.

One idea that comes to my mind is ,

```
cut -d"," -f2-  source >file1
cut -d"," -f1 source | cut -d":" -f1,2 >file2
paste file2 file1
```

But can this be achieved in one shot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the dates and times are of fixed length, just cut by column:

```
$ cut -c1-15,26- < source 
10/19/2011 14:18, 15277, 828, 2964, 1, 1
10/19/2011 14:10, 34298, 898, 3096, 1, 1
```

If everything except minutes can be variable length, use sed:

```
$ cat source 
10/19/2011 14:11:52.911728, 15277, 828, 2964, 1, 1
10/19/2011 14:11:53.915060, 34298, 898, 3096, 1, 1
10/19/2011 4:11:53.915060, 34298, 898, 3096, 1, 1
$ sed 's/\([^:]*:..\)[^,]*\(, .*\)/\1\2/' < source
10/19/2011 14:11, 15277, 828, 2964, 1, 1
10/19/2011 14:11, 34298, 898, 3096, 1, 1
10/19/2011 4:11, 34298, 898, 3096, 1, 1
```

Comment: Not necessary. The hour, might be single digit.

Comment: Hi Vebjorn, do you mind giving a one line explanation on the  1 and 2 that you used at the end of sed?

Comment: @user373215, they are backreferences to the parts of the regular expression that are enclosed by parentheses.